# Error reading hex data from .log file

Tags: c, hex, eof, fgetc

I am having a problem reading hex data from a .log file specified on the command line.
It only prints around 30 lines before and then exits.
Could anyone help me understand why this is happening? I need it to print all the hex data from the input file.

```
int byte;
FILE *Inputfile = stdin;
char *filename = argv[1];
Inputfile = fopen(filename, "r");

while(( byte = fgetc(Inputfile)) != EOF)

     {
         printf(" %02x",byte);
     }

     fclose(Inputfile);
```

Many thanks,

EDIT: Input file is a .log file which looks like this in a hex editor:
[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHQvD.jpg)

Comment: Could you post you input data? You should check `fopen` return.

Comment: Please test the value of `argc` before accessing `argv[1]`, and test the value of `Inputfile` before calling `fgetc`.

Comment: It the linked file the real file you are opening?

Comment: This is not "hex data", this looks like a binary file. You should open it with `"rb"`.

Comment: @unwind - Thank you so much! Just changed it to "rb" and it works now! I don't understand why though, because it is just a .log file which is text not binary?

Comment: @Marcus Your sample input data is not text.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows systems, reading a text file will terminate when the data `0x1a` is read from the file. This is the same value as the `Ctrl-Z` end-of-file when entered on the keyboard.

Sample file data read after opening in binary mode:

```
41 42 43 44 1a 45 46 47
```

Sample file data read after opening in text mode:

```
41 42 43 44
```

Please open the file in binary mode.

```
Inputfile = fopen(filename, "rb");
```

On other systems it could be a different EOF marker.